# Correct way to send money to a smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am following the tutorials in `eth-scaffold` and I'm on Chapter 1.

I get this error

```
eth_sendRawTransaction
  Contract call:       <UnrecognizedContract>
  Transaction:         0x6c9c91bf6e2bacd32eb560b2e1922aacec848dd0dd0d6011d695ee639d57a39c
  From:                0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
  To:                  0x5f3f1dbd7b74c6b46e8c44f98792a1daf8d69154
  Value:               0.5 ETH
  Gas used:            43626 of 43653
  Block #55:           0x616fa7063736af541020d99e3f6d6debad67b694c958565d85f7b958859dff97

  Error: Transaction reverted without a reason
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x1291be112d480055dafd8a610b7d1e203891c274)
      at <UnrecognizedContract>.<unknown> (0x5f3f1dbd7b74c6b46e8c44f98792a1daf8d69154)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I didn't think I was doing anything revolutionary -

```
function stake() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    if (address(this).balance > threshold && block.timestamp <= deadline) {
        exampleExternalContract.complete{value: address(this).balance}();
    }
    emit Stake(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
```

I know that the "if" statement is getting triggered and it's erroring before it hits the emit Stake because I see two Stake events in the UI.

What's a good way to debug this as the error message is pretty unhelpful?

Comment: Please provide more code

Comment: More code, what is (0x1291be112d480055dafd8a610b7d1e203891c274)? Since your using an external contract, is it from an interface?